# How to remove all characters from string except numbers, "," and "." using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, parsing

Please, help me with a regexp for the next task: I have a 'cost' column in some table, but the values there are different:

```
['1.22','1,22','$1.22','1,22$','$ 1.22']
```

I need to remove every character except `digits` and `,` and `.`. So I need to get a value that always can be parsed as Float.

Comment: What have you tried? Best to read some documentation or google before asking your question.

Comment: What do you want '1,22' to be interpreted ?

Comment: Whatever you wrote as code is not valid. Is it an array of strings?

Answer (score 14):

```
a.map {|i| i.gsub(/[^\d,\.]/, '')}
# => ["1.22", "1,22", "1.22", "1,22", "1.22"]
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
yourStr.gsub(/[^0-9,.]/, "")
```

Comment: This was so helpful! Is there any way to keep line breaks in the code? (I'm trying to make a program to clean up a CSV file.)

Comment: @InspectorElement Add `\r` and `\n` to the list of characters, then they won't be removed.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. Just one thing if you want to exclude comma then simply use gsub(/[^0-9.]/, "")

Answer (score 2):

To extract the numbers:

```
a = ["1.22", "1,22", "$1.22", "1,22$", "$ 1.22"]
a.map {|s| s[/[\d.,]+/] }
#=> ["1.22", "1,22", "1.22", "1,22", "1.22"]
```

Assuming commas `,` should be treated like decimal points `.` (as in `'1,22'` -> `1.22`), this should convert your values to float:

```
a = ["1.22", "1,22", "$1.22", "1,22$", "$ 1.22"]
a.map {|s| s[/[\d.,]+/].gsub(',','.').to_f }
#=> [1.22, 1.22, 1.22, 1.22, 1.22]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace all white space, all `'$'` by `''`

Comment: How would you do that in ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Another one:

```
a= ['1.22','1,22','$1.22','1,22$','$ 1.22']
a.map{|i| i[/\d+.\d+/]}
# => ["1.22", "1,22", "1.22", "1,22", "1.22"]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
str = "a1234c324ee4r"    
str.delete("^0-9")
```

It deletes all the characters from string and return all the integers